# Keras Deep Learning IMDB review classification - how to add random review?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am playing with the IMDB dataset from Keras. The code is below. It works fine, but I would have one question - how to now test a random review with the model I've trained? E.g. "I liked how the film depicted New York, but I did not like the film at all".

Could you please help me with this? I'm new to the stuff, so I would really appreciate these few lines of code. Thanks!

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import imdb
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)


max([max(sequence) for sequence in train_data])


word_index = imdb.get_word_index()
reverse_word_index = dict([(value, key) for (key, value) in word_index.items()])
decoded_review = ' '.join([reverse_word_index.get(i - 7, '?') for i in train_data[0]])


import numpy as np

def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.
    return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)


y_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32')
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32')

from keras import models
from keras import layers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
from keras import optimizers

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001),
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
from keras import losses
from keras import metrics

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              loss=losses.binary_crossentropy,
              metrics=[metrics.binary_accuracy])
x_val = x_train[:10000]
partial_x_train = x_train[10000:]

y_val = y_train[:10000]
partial_y_train = y_train[10000:]
history = model.fit(partial_x_train, 
                   partial_y_train,
                   epochs=20,
                   batch_size=512,
                   validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

model.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of the code, you have predicted the results for the test set. If you want to add your own data point, add it as another data point in the test set or you can create a separate data frame similar to x_test. Then run:

```
model.predict(dummy_dataframe)
```